# How to allow a user to enter Value1 and then say Value1 = Value2

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, linq

I know this can be done by an almost endless solution. But I am looking for the most practical way.

I have many times when this sort of thing is needed:

Allow a user to enter a Zip code and then match zip code to predefined states. 
Allow user to select a Country name from a ComboBox and then match country name to country code. 
Names with Colors, Items with Prices, Locations with times, I could go on and on.

So far there are a few ways I've done this is

1 if's:

```
if (input = Value1) { Something = Value1_OtherValue; }
else if (input = Value2) { Something = Value2_OtherValue; }
else if (input = Value2) { Something = Value3_OtherValue; }
else { Messagebox.Show("Error - No Match");}
```

2, using a DB:

```
@"Select Value_OtherValue FROM Table Where ValueList = '"+ Input +'";
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
SQLiteDataAdapter DA = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
DA.Fill(DS);
con.Close();
DataTable DT= DS.Tables[0];
if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Something = DT.Rows[Dt.Rows.Count - 1][0].ToString());
}
else { Messagebox.Show("Error - No Match Found"); }
```

and use either in string or split join or many other string manipulations to extract a value
now these lists would never be thousands or millions MAYBE at absolute max one thousand value pairs, I can image that either a List with a delimiter, an array, using LINQ some how would be the most practical approach, but I just can't wrap my mind around how to start this kind of code.

I understand that i almost NEED a database for this but if I were to go with any type of database type object this would be the ONLY reason to add it to the application, I would have no other use for the database and it would only be changed at most once every 4 or 5 months. So it seems like adding a DB would be overkill in this situation.

Basically I have Value pairs and I want to use the matching value when given the opposite.

Comment: is this ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET webforms or something else(WPF)

Comment: You need to create a City, State, Zip Table.. I have done this before there is actually a web service out there that will allow you to Consume it then you can store the values in your own database.. also use BindingList to bind the dropdown boxes..

Comment: Except for the zipcodes to state issue, what you are describing are just enumerators.  You can use a database as well and if you use EF just map the type tables to enumerations as well using a T4 table.

Comment: @ DJ KRAZE Its for much more then JUST City,State,Zip as stated in question it could be Names with Colors, Items with Prices, Locations with times,Country with Country Code. And web services are not available for every Pair Combination I am looking for.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question about ifs as it doesn't seem to be clear. Concerning the database question, if you store little data you can use CSV format.

Comment: question title is a little confusing, I recommend something along the lines of 'What is the best way to implement a look-up table on a very small website?' or something

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is typically what people use for small database solutions.  Anytime I have some values that I don't want to hard code in the solution (or too many to be practical in a config file), I stick em in a little database.  Usually only a couple of tables, nothing big.  If you want, you can even use Entity Framework with it (there is a SQLite EF provider).

It is not overkill.  Having MSDE or requiring SQL Server would be overkill.  SQLite is made for this.

Comment: So you think creating a table adding the DLL references and all the code required wouldn't be over kill if it was for say 1 set of Pairs and about 200 possible combinations? It seems like an array or List would just be more then enough in these cases.

Comment: I generally try to keep strings and hard coded values out of my code if I can help it.  The setup overhead time necessary to set it up is fairly trivial, nu-get references a couple minutes, a code first entity maybe 10 - 15 (provided you have some experience).  The ability to add and remove values WITHOUT a recompile or messing with the app.config, priceless.  SQLite may be a bit more complex, and hard coding may be easier to implement, but whatever savings you make in the short run may be lost down the line.  Re-usability is the name of the game quite often.

Comment: I am currently using sqlite for this purpose ( as i posted code for this in question) I just felt for little things building a table of 10 rows and 2 columns was just overboard and possibly a loss of performance.

Comment: For little things I suppose, it is.  For small lists (say < a total of 50 values), I will just put something in a config or something.  But if I see that down the road I will have several lists of that size or I might have larger sets of data, I will just go ahead and database it.  I suppose it is a little subjective; what is inordinately more work for one person, may be a snap for another.

Comment: How would you do it using a config file I tried doing this but cannot use multi dimensional arrays and list seem to be immutable

Comment: Do be honest for anything more complex than a simple list of strings or something, I use an XML file that I (de)serialize.  This has worked pretty well for me, and allows user created values to be added/removed pretty easily.  It has the added benefit of being human readable without requiring anything more than a text editor.